# c# interactiveProcessRunner

Tags: c#

Can someone tell me what the `InteractiveProcessRunner` is for? Is it identical to `Process.Start`?

Here is the [class](http://files.codes-sources.com/fichier_fullscreen.aspx?id=50027&f=InteractiveProcessFromService/InteractiveProcessRunner.cs&lang=en).

And here an example :

```
InteractiveProcessRunner runner =  
                       new InteractiveProcessRunner(notepad.exe,hSessionToken);
```

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whit this class you can run a process with the complete environment of the user active: if you call this code from a service, you should find the user mapped resources, the desktop and all the resources that are available when the user is loggen on interactively *even if launched from a service* ie not logged interactively.

Comment: Felice thx for the answer. I have an .exe file that needs my id when it pops up. I did add the path to my .exe file. Is there a way to fill (programatically) in this function the id that the .exe needs ?

Comment: you mean in the command line ? If so the class has a CommandLine public variable you can use

Comment: Can you tell me how to add this in its CommandLine public variable? Plz:). Where is that command line variable? thx Felice

Comment: @elisa, runner.CommandLine="your parameters"; before calling runner.Run()

Comment: thx Felice. Is there a way to access the .exe without seing it in the task manager? What do you say?

Comment: @elisa, I don't think is possible to hide a process from task manager

Comment: yeh...but if it run it inside a service...could it b possible to not see the gui on the desktop? if it is possible how can i do it?:0 can you give me some advices felice?

Comment: @elisa yes you can, use runner.CreateNoWindow=true; have a look at the class code, there is a lot of interesting things inside it.

Comment: i did put runner.CreateNoWindows=true , but the GUI from the exe file still appears...that's why i was asking you...maybe i forget something

Comment: @eliza debug the code inside the class to see if the flag i sproperly propagated to the inner API call.

Comment: there is the desktop variable set and also the normal_priority_class and create_no_window as values. is there a possible way to set the desktop to no desktop view?

Answer (score 0):

The source code to which your link leads referes to this article: http://asprosys.blogspot.com/2009/03/perils-and-pitfalls-of-launching.html which explains the motivation behind it.

Summary: You can't really use `Process.Start()` when you want to start a new process as certain user from a windows service. The `InteractiveProcessRunner` lets you do this (supposedly, never used it so I can't verify it). So it's not the same as `Process.Start()` - it uses a different Windows API.

Comment: ok.thx. If I don't want to see my .exe on desktop even if i know that it runs what should i do if i use this class: InteractiveProcessRunner. Do you have any idea Chris?